# Nginx ignores root directive inside location

Tags: reactjs, docker, nginx

I'm running Nginx as Docker container, with a volume mounted at `/react-frontend` inside the container.

I have a simple configuration for a React app, but the root directive inside location seems to be ignored. I can't understand why.

This single configuration file in `conf.d` directory:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    root /ive/got/a/feeling;

    location /react {
        root /react-frontend/build;
        rewrite /react(.*) $1  break;

        index index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
}
```

Is failing with:

```
2020/08/18 04:32:18 [error] 181#181: *38823 open() "/ive/got/a/feeling/index.html" failed (2: No such file or directory)...
"GET /react/home HTTP/1.1" 404 /ive/got/a/feeling/index.html
```

However, by just moving the root directive to outside the location:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    root /react-frontend/build;

    location /react {
        rewrite /react(.*) $1  break;

        index index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
}
```

It works:

```
"GET /react/home HTTP/1.1" 200 /react-frontend/build/index.html
```

I'm expecting the first config to work. I thought a root directive inside a location would override the server root, but this doesn't seem to happen.
Can anyone explain this?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The `root` directive outside `location {}` is considered as the parent directory, so when you tried to access `/react/*` the server parsed the request and tried to find the `react` directory inside `/ive/got/a/feeling`

what you want to do is to create another root location with `/` and remove the `root` directive that located outside the `location {}`

```
server {
    listen 80;

    location / {
        root /ive/got/a/feeling;
        index index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    location /react {
        root /react-frontend/build;
        rewrite /react(.*) $1  break;

        index index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
}
```